# Computing the sum of the first row of a matrix

Tags: expression-manipulation

I wish to compute for the sum of the reciprocals of the first row of the distance matrix of a particular circulant graph. My code is as follows for the ordinary sum of the first row.

```
d = GraphDistanceMatrix[CirculantGraph[4^3, {1, 2, 4, 6, 8}]];
Total[d[[1]]]
```

However, if I wish to compute for the sum of the reciprocals of the first row, I cannot use the code

```
d = GraphDistanceMatrix[CirculantGraph[4^3, {1, 2, 4, 6, 8}]];
Total[1/d[[1]]]
```

for the $\{1,1\}$ entry of the matrix is $0$. Hence $1/0$ gives an infinity value.

My question is, how can I edit my code so that the $\{1,1\}$ matrix entry is not included in the computation of sum of reciprocals? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: To skip the first element of the first row `Total[1/d[[1, 2 ;;]]]`.

Comment: Thanks @RohitNamjoshi for the comment. Can you explain further what does the part ```d[[1,2 ;;]]]``` of the code is doing? In particular, the 2 and the ;; symbols? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To find out what a symbol such as `;;` means, highlight the symbol and press`F1` for help. For cases where you don't know the position of the zero, use `Total[1/Cases[d[[1]], Except[0]]]`or equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d = GraphDistanceMatrix[CirculantGraph[4^3, {1, 2, 4, 6, 8}]];

Total[1/(d[[1]] /. 0 -> ∞)]
```

> ```
>  1697/60
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work.

```
d = GraphDistanceMatrix[CirculantGraph[4^3, {1, 2, 4, 6, 8}]];
Quiet @ Total[1/d[[1]] /. ComplexInfinity -> 0]
```

> ```
> 1697/60
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the position of the zeros in row-1 of `d`, maybe

```
d[[1]]//Total[1/Pick[#,Clip@#,1]]&
```

> 1697/60

Alternatively:

```
d[[1]]//(1/Pick[#,Clip@#,1]&)//#.UnitStep@#&
```

> 1697/60

If you just want to exclude the first position in row-1 of `d` (as others have pointed out):

```
Total[1/d[[1,2;;]]]
```

> 1697/60

Or

```
Total[1/Rest@d[[1]]]
```

> 1697/60